Package 'ggrain' not found in R
I am having trouble loading the package ggrain (to use with ggplot2). All I really need to do is make a raincloud plot.
I have installed the package multiple ways (both from CRAN and github), and recieve this at the end of installation:
✔ Package 'ggrain' successfully installed.
Warning messages:
1: In utils::install.packages("ggpp", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘ggpp’ had non-zero exit status
2: In utils::install.packages("ggrain", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘ggpp’ had non-zero exit status
3: In utils::install.packages("ggrain", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘ggrain’ had non-zero exit status

However, I try and run library(ggrain) and consistently recieve the error message Error in library(ggrain) : there is no package called ‘ggrain’.
I am using R 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) on macos 12.5.1. The only solution I can find is to update which version of R I am using, but when I try and download the latest release 4.2.2 for macOS I get the message that it cannot be installed on my computer.
I have already tried restarting R, deleting R and redownloading, and clearing my envornment/history/console.
I fear I am either losing my mind or am making a very simple mistake I keep overlooking. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: tried installing ggpp, also cannot find ggpp when trying to load it (shown below)
> install.packages("ggpp")
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘MASS’ is not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:

installing the source package ‘ggpp’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggpp_0.5.8-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2438202 bytes (2.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘ggpp’ ...
** package ‘ggpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘MASS’ 7.3-56 is being loaded, but >= 7.3.58 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/ggpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/h1/bl7yyr4120sdhmgc0mh7ybn80000gn/T/RtmpJinAMm/downloaded_packages’
> library(ggpp)
Error in library(ggpp) : there is no package called ‘ggpp’


Try to install ggpp.  If that works, try to install ggrain again.  If it doesn't work, please show us the error message(s).

Thanks for your response! Original post is updated with my output when trying this.

I checked CRAN, and the current version of MASS is 7.3-61 .  However, your fundamental problem is the extreme age of your MacOS .    If possible, update to at least MacOS 13.X  "Ventura."  Otherwise you will continue to have to try to pull old versions of R and all R packages out of the archives.
